# Deleting a folder from GitHub

Tags: bash, github

I'm trying to delete the folder `mapeditor` from my Java engine on GitHub here (https://github.com/UrbanTwitch/Mystik-RPG)

I'm on Git Bash.. messing around with `rm` and `-rf`but I can't seem to do it. How do I remove `mapeditor` folder from `Mystik-RPG` completely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the `Mystik-RPG` folder:

```
git rm -rf mapeditor
```

Comment: fatal: Not a git repo (or any of the parents directory): .git

Comment: You're in the wrong folder then. Go to the root folder of your local git repository then enter the command.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `git rm` the folder, then `git commit` the removal. Finally, `git push` your new commit to github.

Just deleting the folder won't tell git you wish to have it removed - that would put it into the "tracked but missing" state. You want it to transition to the "untracked" state, which is what `git rm` is for.